# How to read the JSON Error response returned from Server using Libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

I have a requirement where I have to read the error response from backend server which returns 500 Internal Server error. The error response is in JSON Format.

Below is the code snippet used in our application

```
INT CCurlHTTP::HTTPSPost(const CString& endPointUrl, const CString& urlparam,const CString& cookie){
    
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;
    char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    get_request req;
    req.buffer =0;
    req.len =0;
    req.buflen =0;

    if(curl) 
    {
        //add url, headers, and parameters to the request
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, endPointUrl);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, m_httpHeadAccept);
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, m_httpContentType);
        //callback function used to save response
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_String);
        
        req.buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(CHUNK_SIZE);
        req.buflen = CHUNK_SIZE;
        req.len = 0;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&req);
        
        if (!cookie.IsEmpty())
        {
            headers = curl_slist_append(headers, m_DBAuthCertficate); //What is difference between this and line no 118?
            CString pCookie = "DBAuthTicket=" + cookie;
            curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_COOKIE, pCookie);
        }
        else
        {
            headers = curl_slist_append(headers, m_OAuthToken);
        }
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlparam);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
        errbuf[0] = 0;
        
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 512000);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1L);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            /* if errors have occured, tell us wath's wrong with 'result'*/
            m_response.Format("%s", curl_easy_strerror(res));
            return res;
        }

        m_response = (char*)req.buffer;
        m_errDescription = errbuf;
        len = req.len;
        buflen = req.buflen;

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        free(req.buffer);
    }
    return res;
}
/****************************************************************************
Function: CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_String
Description: Read data from the connected URL
Return: String of data and size
****************************************************************************/
size_t CCurlHTTP::CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_String(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    size_t rLen = size*nmemb;
    get_request* req = (get_request*)userdata;
    while(req->buflen < req->len + rLen + 1)
    {
        req->buffer = (unsigned char*)realloc(req->buffer,req->buflen + CHUNK_SIZE);
        req->buflen += CHUNK_SIZE;
    }
    memcpy(&req->buffer[req->len], contents, rLen);
    req->len += rLen;
    req->buffer[req->len] = 0;
    return rLen;
}
```

The above code works fine for the Success 200 OK Requests. It reads the JSON Response just fine. However, when I get a 500 Internal Server error, it does not read the JSON Error response that comes along with it. How do I read the JSON response in this scenario?

Comment: CURLOPT_FAILONERROR? Please also read the descriptions of the tags you applied. Further, why tag this with JSON? Does it relate to JSON, other than coincidently?

Comment: i don't like that `if(curl){actually do stuff}` thing, you guys using that style pretty much never do an `else{throw runtime_error("curl_easy_init failed!");}` 100 lines later.. you should instead do `curl=curl_easy_init();if(!curl){throw runtime_error("curl_easy_init failed!");}` instead. aaalso i'd prefer just keeping the buffer in a std::string, doing `req->buffer->append(contents, size*nmemb);` is much easier than that realloc()+memcpy() thing you're doing, wouldn't you say? just let c++ worry about the allocation stuff since you're using c++ anyway..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting the `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` option to TRUE, you are telling `curl_easy_perform()` to fail immediately with `CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR` on any HTTP response >= 400. It will not call the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback, as it will simply close the connection and not even attempt to read the rest of the response.

To get the response data you want, simply remove the `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` option. Curl's default behavior is to deliver the response data to you regardless of the HTTP response code. In which case, `curl_easy_perform()` will return `CURLE_OK`, and you can then retrieve the response code using `curl_easy_getinfo(CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE)` to check if the HTTP request was successful or not.

---

On a side note, since the code shown is written in C++, I would strongly advise you NOT to use a dynamic `char[]` buffer for `get_request::buffer`. Not only because you are not handling `malloc()`/`realloc()` failures at all, but also because manual memory management should be avoided in C++ in general. Use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` instead, in which case you can eliminate `get_request` in this code altogether, eg:

```
INT CCurlHTTP::HTTPSPost(const CString& endPointUrl, const CString& urlparam,const CString& cookie){
    
    ...

    std::string resp;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &resp);
        
    ...

    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1L);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        /* if errors have occured, tell us what's wrong with 'result'*/
        m_response.Format("%s", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        return res;
    }

    m_response = resp.c_str();
    m_errDescription = errbuf;
    len = resp.size();
    buflen = resp.capacity();

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return res;
}

size_t CCurlHTTP::CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_String(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    size_t rLen = size * nmemb;
    static_cast<std::string*>(userdata)->append(static_cast<char*>(contents), rLen);
    return rLen;
}
```